# XMLHttpRequest to .js file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to experiment some codes. I send XMLHttpRequest to a javascript file where i have just `document.write('hello world');` and i use this code in head section of my HTML document:

```
<script>
        function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "java.js", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

and in java.js there is only single line of code

```
document.write('hello world');
```

what i expect is the result should be only 'hello world' but it prints whole line document.write('hello world');. So is there any way to get only 'hello world' as responseText? Using this files. I know it can be done using PHP/ASp or only with text file but this was the challenge from my college days before two years when i was a student to do this using javascript file and still i don't have i dear how to get this. I want to know this from the excellent brains of world on stack overflow.

Comment: Just execute the code.

Comment: use a script tag to inject `Hello World` in-place, simple ajax won't work for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it is by `eval`ing the response and you would do well to know the side-effects of using `eval`.

Replace `xmlhttp.responseText` with `eval(xmlhttp.responseText)` and it should work.

**Note:** Use caution while `eval`ing!

Just be sure to not send any markup like `<script>` in the response as `eval` will not have the desired effect then.

Answer (score -1):

xmlhttp.responseText return a string. So just put hello world in your java.js file.
In fact java.js will not execute javascript language.

Comment: The challenge was accepted and solved at those days so if you don't know then don't think it is not possible.

Comment: Sorry trying to help... And what was the solution?